# Flutter how to detect Line feed (LF)

Tags: flutter

how can i detect line feed in Flutter?
as I know CR can be detected by "\n" and it's working fine.
this is the code I used for CR

```
 if (value.toString().contains("\n")) {
                                        fetchProducts(value);
                                       
                                      } else {}
                                    },
```

I tried "\r" but its not working.
I am Using TextFormFiled and the setting in the device was set to send LF after reading a barcode

Comment: You have it backwards. `\r` corresponds to CR (carriage return), hence the "r". `\n` corresponds to a "new line" (hence the "n"), which sometimes is represented by LF (line feed).

Comment: @jamesdlin i tried \r and \n its not working , if I open for example the notes and read barcode its reading each barcode in a new line but in flutter its not

Comment: It might help if you posted reproducible code that demonstrated the problem and posted the code points of the `String` that you think contains a linefeed (or carriage return) by printing `value.toString().runes`.

Comment: thanks a lot my mistake i was putting the keyboardType as Numbers so this will not let the LF to be red

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unicode value for LF, U+000A:

```
if (value.toString().contains("\u{000a}")) {
    fetchProducts(value);
   
} else {}

},
```

EDIT

What is the type of `value`? In my code, to be sure that I'm converting correctly from bytes to `String`, instead of using `toString` I'm using this:

```
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;
[...]
String message = utf8.decode(data);
```

Comment: hi its not working , iam using TextFormFiled and its not detecting it at all , I made the settings for the device to send LF after reading but its not reading it

Comment: Don't know what to say, I'm using a very similar code in a very similar situation (device  sending data over TCP/IP to flutter desktop app) and I can detect any kind of special character in this way (CR, LF, ETX, STX, and so on).
PS: wait, check my answer, I added something

Comment: i think there is someything i bthe device itself , course if I use Zebra TC26 or Tc56 or Tc25 it works fine but with a new device call point mobile its not detecting , but thanks